# Adding up Values of a row in mysql database in a dynamic table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with number of fields that change with operation. To simplify it to the table below

```
STUDENT MATHS   PHYSICS BIOLOGY TOTAL

PAUL      89      87      65    

JOHN      56      89      54
```

The aim is to sum up the scores of each student in the total column. I have written a small php code to that effect but is does not given me the result in total. I have also tried other variation (which i may not want to post) that did not work. Any suggestions please.

```
$table = 'scores';
$total = '';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table");

if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);
//table to display student scores 
echo "<table><tr>";

for ($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++) {
   $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
   echo "<th>$field->name</td>";
} 

echo "</tr>\n";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $student_id=$row->student_id;
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $cell) {
        echo "<td> $cell </td>";
    }
    // calcuate the total score of each record
    $total =($cell + $total);
    echo "</tr>\n";
    echo 'The total = '.$total;
}

// functio to insert the total scores t the table
function tScore($table, $student_id, $total) {
    $sqlCommand = "UPDATE $table SET total='$total' WHERE student_id='$student_id' "; 
    $query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die ('Sorry something went wrong while inserting Subjects Scores'); 

    return $total;
    return $student_id;
}
?>
```

Comment: See normalisation. A database table is not a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like this

```
$sel="select *,(sum(Maths)+sum(Physics)+sum(Biology)) as Total from sum group by Student";
```

Comment: Thank you, That would work only that the fields are dynamic and would change along the operation, say another course 'Language' would be added. I don't want to have to change the codes every time this happens